# Connect to a VIEW on an SQL database using SAS

Tags: sql-server, sas

is it possible to connect to a VIEW on an SQL Server database using SAS?

I am not a SAS user, I work in IT but one of my user divisions need to access some data that's on our Live server scattered over a few tables.  I'd rather not give access to the entire set of tables on which the data resides, I'd like to create a view on our live SQL server and give them read access to only the view, and then have them connect to it using SAS.

They currently can connect to a different database table on our SQL server using an ODBC connection.  But I got them to send me a screen grab of the steps they follow.  The 'Open Tables' screen that appears after they've selected their ODBC connection on the 'Data Source' window doesn't seem to list Views.

Comment: The short answer is yes but we probably need a little more info to help.  Are your users using SAS Enterprise Guide?

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information.  In addition to answering Rob's question (how are they connecting), please include the code itself they're using to connect (with IP/password/username XXXed out), and what steps they're taking.  Also, does the SQL server (I assume this is MS Sql Server?) have its tables and/or views in schemas?

Comment: I agree with Robert and Joe, more information is needed to really be able to answer your question. But I can tell you from experience that if you're using the `proc sql` passthrough facility, you should theoretically be able to get the data from a view under the right circumstances.