# Connect to SQL View From SAS EG

Tags: sql-server, sas, odbc, enterprise-guide

I have set up an ODBC connection to a SQL server and I can see all of the tables I need in the database, is there a way to connect to a view within the same database? Below is the code I have. There was a question posted below however no answer was provided due to lack of detail. I was hoping the extra detail on here may help.

```
LIBNAME MYLIB ODBC  DSN='MYDBUAT' SCHEMA=MYSUAT READ_LOCK_TYPE=NOLOCK;
```

[Connect to a VIEW on an SQL database using SAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22833432/connect-to-a-view-on-an-sql-database-using-sas)

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the view in the same schema?  There's nothing inherently preventing you from selecting from a view as opposed to a table, as long as it's set up in the database the same way as the tables.

Comment: If you can see tables but can't see the view, I would suggest you check the permissions on the view.  Also, perhaps try connecting to the database with a SQL server client, to see if you can see the view.  If you can't see them from SQL Server Management studio, or whatever, then it's definitely a SQL Server issue, not a SAS issue.

Comment: Is the name of the view also valid as a SAS membername? Is it 32 characters or less and start with letter or underscore? Perhaps that is why you cannot access it?

Comment: Hi - thanks for your responses. I think it could be the length of the view name which is 38 characters long. I have just tried connecting to one with a smaller name and I had no issues. I don't suppose there is away around this? other than changing the name of the view in SQL which I wont have permission to do

Comment: That sounds likely to be a reportable bug in SAS. Identifier length limits should be inherited from the data sources SAS lists as compatible, not imposed thereon by SAS.